# How to use `[c(),]` to subset dataframe when `c()` is `0`?

Tags: r

`del_folder` is variable,when `del_folder` is `0`,`{.[-del_folder,]}` output `0rows`.
How to solve this problem?

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  cola = c('1',NA,'c','1','1','e','1',NA,'c','d'),
  colb = c("A",NA,"C","D",'a','b','c','d','c','d'),
  colc = c('a',NA,'c','d','a',NA,'c',NA,'c','d'),stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

del_folder<-c(0,3)
df1 %>% {.[-del_folder,]}

#without delete any row,but output has 0rows?
del_folder<-c(0)
df1 %>% {.[-del_folder,]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check the values in `del_folder` and run the command only when it has at least one value which is not 0.

```
if(any(del_folder != 0)) df1 <- df1 %>% {.[-del_folder,]}
```

Comment: Is there any function cover `del_folder <- c(0)` without further condition?